# Formato de data da session Oracle para executar procedure armazenada

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Fala galera, tudo bom? Eu estou com um probleminha que talvez seja simples de resolver, mas não consegui encontrar solução até o momento.

Eu tenho procedures armazenadas no banco oracle que precisam ser executadas, porem estou montando essas execuções de forma dinâmica usando o EntityManager.
O problema em si é o seguinte, eu tenho uma procedure que precisa de um parametro data, mas a procedure está usando o formato DD-MM-YYYY (isso não pode ser alterado, por ser um código legado que ainda está sendo utilziado). Eu consigo formatar a data na camada java e deixar nesse formato DD-MM-YYYY, porem quando eu mando executar a session do oracle está convertendo aparentemente, para o formato que está como padrão no banco DD-MON-RR e ao passar essa data para a procedure, ocorre um erro que retorna uma mensagem que apresenta a data recebido no formato '01/01/0020'.

Teria alguma forma de eu configurar esse formado para a sessão durante a conexão na camada Java?
Ou alguma forma de eu impedir que o oracle converta a data?
Segue abaixo um exemplo de uma das tentativas de execução.

Edit: Usando Alter Session resolve, porem precisaria de uma forma de fazer isso na camada java.

[Print de parte do código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2RZI.png)

Comment: Tentou um alter session ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119

Comment: Alter Session resolve, mas não é viavel eu alterar a sessão de todas as bases que são necessárias, queria saber se tem uma forma de configurar isso em código

Comment: Uma trigger de logon talvez , não sei como fazer para saber se o connect veio do Java https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=after-logon-trigger-200510  https://community.oracle.com/thread/5323?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Pode ser uma opção, mas seria ideal algo direto pelo java

Comment: Eu tenho por hábito sempre no sql e no plsql informar o formato dadata e nunca assumir o da session , mas mecher em legado pode ser complicado , a ideia da trigger seria um paliativo , onde trabalho não usamos Java então não tive esta experiência. Viu isto ? https://community.oracle.com/thread/386043?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Não tinha testado essa execução do alter session com JDBC, vou tentar

Comment: Costumo dizer , se não estiver programando o fator de dobra da Interprise , alguém já passou pelo seu mesmo problema ... :)

Comment: kkkk faz sentido

Comment: @Motta resolvido, com o proprio jpa.
  Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            session.doWork(connection -> {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy'");
                preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                preparedStatement.close();
            });

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada, utilizando o entitymanger para alterar a sessão.

```
      Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                session.doWork(connection -> {
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy'");
                    preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                });
```

Comment: O que eu disse hoje aqui neste site e repito , fora você estar programando a fusão de dobra da Interprise , alguém já passou pelo seu problema ...